# Handling events in Haskell

Tags: haskell, event-handling, ghc, typeclass

I would like to implement the following scenario in Haskell. I have an
enumerable set of 'events' defined like this:

```
data MyEvent = Event1
             | Event2
             | Event3
```

I want to define handlers for these events to be used in the following way:

```
eventLoop :: Handler h => h -> IO ()
eventLoop currentHandler = do
    event <- getNextEvent
    nextHandler <- currentHandler event
    eventLoop nextHandler
```

Basically I want handlers to be able to return themselves or another handler to
handle future events. It's the type of handlers I'm not sure about.

My first idea was to define handlers as simple functions, but their type would
get infinitely long:

```
myHandler :: Event -> IO (Event -> IO (Event -> ... ))
```

I suspect this can be solved with a type class, where each handler would need
to implement a function to handle events (which in turn returns another type of
the same class), but the recursive definition would still apply. Can someone
more well versed in the type system point me in the right direction? I also
welcome any different takes on this.

Thanks!

Comment: I think `MyHandler :: [Event] -> [IO ()]` and `eventLoop :: ([Event] -> [IO ()]) -> IO ()` might be a better approach.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, "infinite" types usually amount to unrolled recursive types. So one thing you could do is make the recursion explicit using a `newtype`:

```
newtype Handler = Handler { runHandler :: Event -> IO Handler }
```

This is also probably the simplest solution, because it avoids the need to juggle type classes and different instances in order to get different behaviors--each handler can pick what it returns, since they have a uniform interface.

Note that, in many cases, defining a type class to solve this kind of problem is completely superfluous. If you're dealing with a polymorphic type `Handler h => h`, all you can do with that type is use the type class's functions on it. If the functions defined on that type class are simple, you can save yourself a lot of hassle by conceptually "pre-applying" them.